# DropDown tree with search

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I fetch a bunch of categories for a `DropDown` tree, and have to implement search in this dropdown. If there is a match in one of the elements, it should also get all parents to display in the dropdown hierarchy. The number of childnodes is unknown, and can be changed at any given time (example has only 3 levels but can be 5 also).

The search applies on every ScrapCategory description.

[image]

I get the expected result but I would love to see this in \$O(N)\$.

```cs
public sealed class ScrapCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Level { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public ScrapCategory[] Filter(ScrapCategory[] categories, string searchString)
{
    var result = new List<ScrapCategory>();

    foreach (ScrapCategory category in categories)
    {
        if (category.Description.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            result.Add(category);

        if (category.ParentId > 0)
        {
            int parentId = category.ParentId;

            while (parentId > 0)
            {
                var parent = categories.Where(x => x.Id == parentId)?.First();
                if (!result.Contains(parent))
                    result.Add(parent);
                parentId = parent.ParentId;
            }
        }
    }

    return result.OrderBy(x => x.Level).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Seems like a problem you want to use a Tree structure for. Why is _ScrapCategory_ a flat object (with Id's rather than references to other family members), and are you in the possibility to change the definition of that class?

Comment: We are re-writing 30 year old Pascal/Delphi applications to a new .NET stack but we múst use the existing DB model, procedures, and even use existing queries. We pass ScrapCategory[] to FE and they create the DropDown. ScrapCategory is the representation of how it is stored in DB.

Comment: There is a performance tag that you can add if performance is an issue. I take it that the image showing the drop down menu is from a requirements document. That may make some of the reviewers on this site feel that the question is too vague. Is it possible for you to post all classes involved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
>     var result = new List<ScrapCategory>();
>     ...
>                 if (!result.Contains(parent))
> ```

There's one performance problem. Use a data structure which gives fast `Contains` checks: typically `HashSet<>`.

---

> ```
>                 var parent = categories.Where(x => x.Id == parentId)?.First();
> ```

There's another one. I assume that IDs are unique, in which case `lookup = categories.ToDictionary(category => category.Id)` will give you a fast hash map from ID to category.

---

> ```
>         if (category.Description.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
>             result.Add(category);
>
>         if (category.ParentId > 0)
>         {
>             int parentId = category.ParentId;
>
>             while (parentId > 0)
>             {
>                 ...
>             }
>         }
> ```

Is this definitely correct? It's not supposed to be

```
        if (category.Description.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            result.Add(category);

            if (category.ParentId > 0)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

?

Either way, the `if (category.ParentId > 0)` is pointless. The test is repeated by the `while` loop, and a single assignment to a local variable isn't going to be a performance bottleneck.

---

> ```
>                 if (!result.Contains(parent))
>                     result.Add(parent);
> ```

Note that with the suggestion of making `result` a `HashSet` it becomes preferable to just call `Add`, which returns a `bool` to tell you whether it changed anything. If it didn't, you can break out of the loop, because you know that all of the further ancestors have already been added.

---

The effect of these changes (except the one I'm unsure about) is

```
public ScrapCategory[] Filter(ScrapCategory[] categories, string searchString)
{
    var lookup = categories.ToDictionary(category => category.Id);
    var result = new HashSet<ScrapCategory>();

    foreach (ScrapCategory category in categories)
    {
        if (category.Description.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            result.Add(category);

        int parentId = category.ParentId;
        while (parentId > 0)
        {
            var parent = lookup[parentId];
            if (!result.Add(parent))
                break;
            parentId = parent.ParentId;
        }
    }

    return result.OrderBy(x => x.Level).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Your solution with `HashSet<>` exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks a lot for the answer and explanation!

Answer (score 3):

A possibility is to store the parents as we go so we don't need to keep searching though the input array. 
 
We can use a dictionary to look up the parents by id.

If we can guarantee that the ancestors for a category all appear in the array before the category then we can do this in one pass.

Reading through the array we add each category to the dictionary, keyed to its id.
We can also use the dictionary entry to show if a given item has already been added to the result (this removes the need for the `Contains()` check)

Then, if it has a parent, we get the parent from the dictionary and if it hasn't been added, add it, and then repeat for the parent't parent (if any), recursing up the tree.

```
private static Category[] Filter(IEnumerable<Category> categories, string searchString)
{
    var ret = new List<Category>();
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, DictEntry>();
    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        dict.Add(category.Id, new DictEntry(category));
        if (category.Description.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            ret.Add(category);
            dict[category.Id].Added = true;

            var parentId = category.ParentId;

            while (true)
            {
                if (parentId == 0) break;
                var parent = dict[parentId].Category;

                if (!dict[parent.Id].Added)
                {
                    ret.Add(parent);
                    dict[parent.Id].Added = true;
                }
                parentId = parent.ParentId;

            }
        }
    }
    return ret.OrderBy(n => n.Level).ToArray();
}
```

If we cannot guarantee that the ancestors appear ahead of the category then we can do it in two passes.  Not O(N) (AFAIK) but still should be notably faster than searching all the inputs for each ancestor.

```
private Category[] Filter(IEnumerable<Category> categories, string searchString)
{
    var ret = new List<Category>();
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, DictEntry>();
    foreach(var category in categories)
    {
        dict.Add(category.Id, new DictEntry(category));
        if(category.Description.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >=0)
        {
            ret.Add(category);
            dict[category.Id].Added = true;
        }
    }

    var ancestors = new List<Category>();
    foreach(var category in ret)
    {
        var parentId = category.ParentId;

        while(true)
        {
            if (parentId == 0) break;
            var parent = dict[parentId].Category;

            if(!dict[parent.Id].Added)
            {
                ancestors.Add(parent);
                dict[parent.Id].Added = true;
            }
            parentId = parent.ParentId;

        }

    }
    return ret.Concat(ancestors).OrderBy(n => n.Level).ToArray();
}
```

**Other points:**

I would push for having the input being `IEnumerable<ScrapCategory>` rather than `ScrapCategory[]`.  The array requirement limits without adding anything useful.

**Edit - Add missing helper class**

```
class DictEntry
{
    public DictEntry(Category category)
    {
        Category = category;
        Added = false;
    }
    public Category Category { get; }
    public bool Added { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but what is `DictEntry`? Why not use `Category` (or `ScrapCategory`)?

Comment: @JAD I wanted to use the added field as well as the Category so that we don't have to check to see if it is already in the list before we add it again. Faster than the `if (!result.Contains(parent))` in the original code.

Comment: According to the OP, their model is fixed, so adding fields doesn't really fly. If you're worried about duplicate items in your resultslist, use a `HashSet<Category>`.

Comment: @JAD Adding fields? I'm not sure what you mean. Added is part of the DictEntry which doesn't touch the model. A HashSet<ScrapCategory> will work but could lead to unneeded processing - say we have two sibling grandchildren that meet the search criteria. Grandchild 1 (GC1) adds its parent (P1) and then we add its parent (GP1). We match GC2, we now add its parent (P1) and then its parent (CP1).  OK, not a great deal of extra processing but why not short circuit it by saying you (and all your ancestors) have already been added so just move onto the next item?

Comment: I'm not familiar with dictentry, can't find anything on it in the msdn docs either. Hence my initial question.

Comment: @JAD My bad, I missed copying that class. Adding now